# In Android, how can I enable a checkBox only if there is text in a textView?

Tags: android, checkbox, textview

In my layout I have a textView and a checkBox. I like to enable the checkBox only if the user enters text in the textView. If the user removes the text in the textView, the checkBox should get grayed out again.

Can you please give me some idea how I might be able to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by `textView` you mean `editText` right?

In `EditText` there is a method which you can set a text change listener. The method name is `addTextChangedListener` and inside there you can check whether the input size is 0 or not. So here is the sample code:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int 
            i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            checkBox.setEnabled(editable.toString().length() > 0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. It also works for textView. Thank you

Comment: Thank to you. I didn't know I could use it for `textView`!